# Facebook SDK: create ad account says "(#270) Development access is not allowed to access business API post:Business\/adaccount."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

We are attempting to follow the advice given [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/#Creating) to create an ad account for a 3rd party user, like this:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/<BUSINESS_ID>/adaccount -F "name=ad account" -F "currency=EUR" -F "timezone_id=1" -F "end_advertiser=NONE" -F "media_agency=NONE" -F "partner=NONE"   -F "access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

This command results in:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#270) Development access is not allowed to access business API post:Business\/adaccount.","type":"OAuthException","code":270,"fbtrace_id":"A0VK_j5lhkOXn0Cc5W9WZSx"}}
```

The BUSINESS_ID specified here is for our actual live (but not yet Facebook-validated) business, as we have been unable to find any explanation of how to obtain a test BUSINESS_ID for dev.

The goal here is to be able to create an ad account for an end user, which we will manage. The end user must not be able to modify the ad campaigns that we will eventually be creating via this account.

What are we doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your app is still in Development mode, which in the case of Facebook API, some of the permissions, they do not allow access when your app is in development mode. For example: when you need to receive notifications in your webhooks.

You can check your development mode in the developer dashboard. I think this is the issue in your case.

Comment: So, let me see if I understand this... We need our app to be in production before we can test this feature, but in order to submit the app for production, it must first be validated by FB, and in order for this to happen, we need to have all features implemented, but in order to implement this feature, we would need to test this feature, but in we need our app to be in production before we can test this feature, but in order to submit the app for production, it must first be validated by FB, and in order for this to happen... oops, I'm running out of characters here.

Comment: You can try using the access token which belongs to the admin of the app and admin of the ad account. I think that's one of the restrictions you have in this case. Some of the Features in Facebook have sensitive functionalities such as Ads permissions, that's one of the reasons they won't let you access information when you are in Dev mode.

Comment: OK, I have tried using an access token of an admin of the (test) app.  Same result. I don't understand, however, when you say "and admin of the ad account". There is no ad account... as that is exactly what we are trying to create.

Comment: You can go to https://business.facebook.com and create an account if you already don't have one, that is basically the business account for your business, inside you have the ad account option. At this point you should have access to your pages and manage your ads in the dashboard. You can also add people to the account where you can grant them privileges. Once you have done this, try to retrieve the token and try again.

Comment: We just tried one more time, this time using the prod app ID, and... a new error message!  "(#294) Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended permission for ads_management"  This almost feels like progress? Of course, this also makes no sense to us, as we do request ads_management scope when obtaining the token, so... not sure what else is needed here.

Comment: Oh no... I see now.  The FB login window says "Submit for Login Review /
Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook," and I am advised to submit the app for review. Which sends us back to square 1.

Comment: Ok, that might be the case, basically once your app is reviewed and approved, you no longer need to have the app in Dev mode. Make sure you apply the ads_management permission with any of the dependent permission that you require, usually it's a page permission. Check this link out: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_engagement

I think this is the permission you are suppose to apply with. Also provide valid use cases and videos in order to get it approved at once.